# SocketIo: Unable to emit event from react frontend to node backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I have a basic react app setup on 3000 with a socketio server running via express on 5000. My Problem is that while I'm able to connect to the socketio server and receive events emitted from the server on the client, I am not able to emit events from the client to the server.

I've found this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67342700/emit-socket-io-event-from-react-app-and-doesnt-receive-it-at-node-js-server), though it doesn't help because in that case the user had failed to reference the correct socket object, a problem which I am not having here.

Here's the part in my react app where I talk to the server:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useChat } from '../contexts/ChatContext';
import queryString from 'query-string';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

let socket;

const Chat = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { chatState } = useChat();
  console.log('chat context', chatState);
  const ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:5000';

  useEffect(() => {
    // const { name, room } = queryString.parse(location.search);
    socket = io(ENDPOINT);

    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('socket connected');
      console.log(socket);
    });

    socket.emit('test', 'test');
  }, [chatState, ENDPOINT]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to Chat</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

And here's my server:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
  },
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('we have a connection');

  socket.on('test', (args) => console.log(args));

  socket.disconnect(() => console.log('a user disconnected'));
});

app.use('/', require('./router'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

httpServer.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

You can see that I am emitting 'test' event type with data payload 'test' and listening for 'test' via socket.on in the server. When my component loads, I see "we have a connection" and nothing else.

full repo [here](https://github.com/coreymunn3/chat-app-demo)

Comment: by calling `socket.disconnect` you are disconnecting the moment a connection event is recieved.

Answer (score 0):

As about14sheep said, I was immediately disconnecting instead of listening for a disconnect.

The corrected server code is:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('we have a connection');

  socket.on('test', (args) => console.log(args));

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('a user disconnected');
  });
});
```